# Creating folders inside zip file in NAnt

Tags: build, zip, directory, nant

At the end of a NAnt script, the last step is to create a ZIP file.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
<zip zipfile="${target.dropfile}">
    <fileset basedir="${somefolder}">
        <include name="file1.dll" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset basedir="${someotherfolder}">
        <include name="file2.dll" />
    </fileset>
    <!-- ...etc ... -->
</zip>
```

This works fine, but I want the zip file to be a little more organized. I want the zip file to contain two folders, folder1 and folder2, and I want file1.dll to be in folder1 and file2.dll to be in folder2. Is there any way of doing this within the `<zip />` task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the prefix variable.

```
<zip zipfile="${target.dropfile}">
    <fileset basedir="${somefolder}" prefix="folder1">
        <include name="file1.dll" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset basedir="${someotherfolder}" prefix="folder2">
        <include name="file2.dll" />
    </fileset>
    <!-- ...etc ... -->
</zip>
```

Comment: I get `Unexpected attribute "prefix" on element <include>.` - am I using an old version of NAnt?

Comment: So it looks like prefix should be put on the fileset, not on the include (corrected)